# How can we sum/perform other functions in row wise and also removing factors/levels

Tags: r

Below is my data

```
name  1day  2day  3day
a      20    30    40
b      30    10     0
c      12     5     3
```

In R, if i perform `sum(mydata[2,])`
then i am getting below error:

> ```
> Error in Summary.factor(c(105L, 76L, 95L, 98L, 106L, 29L), na.rm = FALSE) : 
>   ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors
> ```

1. could you please tell me, how to get b total paid amount?
2. how to remove the factors.

Also please suggest me other alternatives.

Comment: You have to convert factors to num eric if you want to manipulate your data without loss of information. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information) out.

Comment: Your first column is a factor. If you want to sum over the second *row*, you could do `sum(mydata[2,-1])` (in order to ignore the first column). If you want to sum over second *column*, you should put the index *after* the comma, i.e. `sum(mydata[,2])`. Also, in order to run over all the rows, you could do `rowSums(mydata[-1])`

Answer (score 2):

We don't have to remove non numeric columns. We just need to make sure we aren't summing non numeric columns (character, factor, logical for example). `sum(2, "c")` will give us an error for this reason. If we have a column of logical type `sum` will treat `FALSE` as 0 and `TRUE` as 1. See `?sum` for more info.

With base R as @DavidArenburg mentions, we can do:

```
df$row_sum <- rowSums(df[-1])
df
```

> ```
>   name X1day X2day X3day row_sum
> 1    a    20    30    40      90
> 2    b    30    10     0      40
> 3    c    12     5     3      20
> ```

If we have other columns that aren't numeric and shouldn't be summed, we can use `sapply` to only sum rows of columns that are numeric:

```
df$row_sum <- rowSums(df[, sapply(df, is.numeric)])
df
```

> ```
>   name X1day X2day X3day row_sum
> 1    a    20    30    40      90
> 2    b    30    10     0      40
> 3    c    12     5     3      20
> ```

This would be useful when removing the first column isn't enough. For example, if there is a forth column that is of character type.

@Jaap also [mentioned](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/41940318#41940318) another base R solution using `Reduce`:

```
Reduce('+', df[,-1])

# again, if removing the first column isn't enough we can do
Reduce('+', df[, sapply(df, is.numeric)])
```

Alternatively, with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(row_sum = sum(X1day, X2day, X3day))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 5
>   name  X1day X2day X3day row_sum
>   <chr> <int> <int> <int>   <int>
> 1 a        20    30    40      90
> 2 b        30    10     0      40
> 3 c        12     5     3      20
> ```

---

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "name  1day  2day  3day
a      20    30    40
b      30    10     0
c      12     5     3", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactor = FALSE)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP fully understood the issue. If you 'remove the factor' from the first column, it still will throw because it is a character. Your answer provides a solution but a bit more explanation might help.

Comment: Hi, One more question. 

a <- 85.37 102.42  85.97 104.59  72.60  97.21
b<- 2.07 58.36 53.55 70.96 49.11 66.52
c<- SHREYA, BHAWSAR, RAVI, MOHAN, GANDHI, KARTHIK

When i use cbind to combine all vectors, then the names ie. c is getting as some numbers.

how to get it as names like

c            a        b
shreya  85        3
bhawsar 102    58

please help